# set row in a specific result mysql php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can i display a specific result to be in the fourth place after executing a query?

For example, i have 10 rows. one of the rows have id = 4.
I want the the row with the id = 4 will always be in the fourth place.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To set it to the first place you could use this:

```
SELECT if(id=4,0,1) AS sort1, ...
...
ORDER BY sort1 ASC, ...
```

The question is, what are the criteria for sorting your other rows?
If there are ids 1, 2, 3 you could place them before id 4 in this way, but without further details I don't know if this makes sense:

```
SELECT if(id<=4,id,5) AS sort1, ...
...
ORDER BY sort1 ASC, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
........
ORDER BY id = 4 DESC;
```